# Getting Emacs Tabs to Indent 2 ( Using Emacs Live )

Tags: emacs, tabs

What I want:
Tabs to be a length of 2.

What I have:
Tabbing moves me several spaces. Ether 2 spaces or 6. Seemingly randomly.
And they are spaces, literally, it seems. In that if press tab then I move up 6 characters, I press backspaces and it moves me back 1 ( to the 5th position).

So tabs move me to either a mod 2 or a mod 6 location all via spaces.

I want it to move me two at a time via tabs.

I have hacked around with different commands to no avail. = (

Thank you

Edit:

Also why the heck is this article titled tabs are evil when it says they are necessary...

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabsAreEvil

Comment: Indentation is complicated in Emacs, I'm afraid (it tends to take people by surprise). Without knowing which modes you're talking about, it's hard to help, so give us some more details. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryIndentation has lots of information on the subject in general.

Comment: Also "I have hacked around with different commands to no avail" tells us nothing useful. Tell us *what you've tried*, not that "I tried something, but I'm not going to tell you what it was".

Comment: Regarding the TabsAreEvil page, I *think* originally it was rather more emphatically in line with its title? Reading it now, it comes across as more broad-minded than I remember it being :) (although I've always preferred the SmartTabs approach myself, so I probably didn't pay too much attention to TabsAreEvil).